# unsure of how 2-d lists work in python

Tags: python, list

Need to make a 6x8 matrix. In this matrix, need to assign values to various cells within the matrix and then simulate a heating/cooling system. Before I get there though, I need to make sure this is right. Is this how you make rows and columns? Does it matter that it does not display this way when printed? Like I said I need to assign values to each of theses cells, does it matter that some already have a value by the way I made the lists? Is there a way to make the list without any initial values?

```
matrix = [] # Create an empty list
numberOfRows = 6
numberOfColumns = 8
for row in range(0, numberOfRows):
    matrix.append([]) # Add an empty new row
    for column in range(0, numberOfColumns):
        matrix[row].append(column)

print(matrix) 



[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a multidimensional list in Python, nor a list without any values.

Comment: [use `numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) if you want to deal with matrices, much easier

Comment: well according to my teacher and another way I printed this list in a different form, you are incorrect on both counts. also, we are using numpy in the future but now he wants us to work on it with lists

Comment: Well, if we are wrong then perhaps go back to your teacher and ask them how to do this?

Comment: i think what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams means is that there is no technical thing as a multidimensional list because what you are making is actually a list of lists, ie nested lists. (it can be argued that those are different things). and by list without any values, yes there can be empty lists but you cant have a list with a set size with no values like you would be able to in C because of the way that lists are made and allocated

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a good method. However, it is much easier and more pythonic to use list comprehension : `matrix = [list(range(numberOfColumns)) for _ in range(numberOfRows)]`

And yes, you can make a list with no value : `[]` or `list()`

And even a 2-dimensional list : `[[]]`

However, it has no use.

Comment: thanks for actually answering my question and giving me further advice

Comment: In fact empty lists have a lot of uses.

Comment: Sure, but not for matrixes. Look at that beauty : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63553/47040

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to make 2D arrays, but a few comments:

- You may consider initializing the elements to 0 (or -1) by changing the last line to `matrix[row].append(0)`.
  This is mostly a design choice. For example, if, in your program, later on you do not change the values at every position, then you will be left with old values from the initialization.
- You can re-write `range(0, numberOfRows)` to `range(numberOfRows)`; it starts from 0 by default.
- List comprehension, as Labo has already mentioned